# Simplifiying the trigonometry equation to show that triangle is isosceles

Tags: geometry, trigonometry

In a triangle $ABC$ , $X$ is a point inside it , its given that Angle $BAX = 10^\circ$ , Angle $ABX = 20^\circ$ , Angle $XAC = 40^\circ$ and Angle $XCA = 30^\circ$, prove that triangle is isosceles.

> My method was using trigonometry to arrive at value of the unknown angles, and then showing its isoceles. Lets call Angle $XCB$ to be $\alpha$, then applying sin rule on triangle $ABX$ and $AXC$, and similarly for other two pairs keeping in mind one side is common to them, we get arrive at $\sin(\alpha)\sin 20^\circ\sin40^\circ  = \sin(80^\circ -\alpha) \sin 10^\circ \sin 30^\circ$. Now my question is how do we solve such trigonometric equation in a restricted domain to show that only solution to this is $20^\circ$? Implying $AB = BC$.

Comment: Why do not you use geometric method?, it may be easier.

Comment: Actually geometric method most of the times dont strike me much thats why i go with trigonometry @sirous , although you may provide that solution with the above query i asked , i can accept both :)

Comment: You say $\alpha=20^o$. I checked it does not satisfy your equation.

Comment: I suppose $AB=BC$ is wrong. Consider case $AC=BC$.

Comment: @sirous sin10° sin30° sin 60° =        sin^2 20°  sin40°

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is an approach using the Law of Sines and the Law of Cosines, that is not too bad.

[image]
$$
\begin{align}
BX
&=AB\,\frac{\sin\left(10^{\large\circ}\right)}{\sin\left(150^{\large\circ}\right)}\tag{1a}\\[6pt]
&=2AB\sin\left(10^{\large\circ}\right)\tag{1b}\\[6pt]
CX
&=AX\,\frac{\sin\left(40^{\large\circ}\right)}{\sin\left(30^{\large\circ}\right)}\tag{2a}\\
&=AB\,\frac{\sin\left(20^{\large\circ}\right)}{\sin\left(150^{\large\circ}\right)}\,\frac{\sin\left(40^{\large\circ}\right)}{\sin\left(30^{\large\circ}\right)}\tag{2b}\\[6pt]
&=4AB\sin\left(20^{\large\circ}\right)\sin\left(40^{\large\circ}\right)\tag{2c}\\[12pt]
BC^2
&=BX^2+CX^2-2BX\,CX\,\cos\left(100^{\large\circ}\right)\tag{3a}\\[6pt]
&=AB^2\left(4\sin^2\left(10^{\large\circ}\right)+16\sin^2\left(20^{\large\circ}\right)\sin^2\left(40^{\large\circ}\right)\right.\\
&\phantom{=AB^2\left(\right.}\left.{}-16\sin\left(10^{\large\circ}\right)\sin\left(20^{\large\circ}\right)\sin\left(40^{\large\circ}\right)\cos\left(100^{\large\circ}\right)\right)\tag{3b}\\[6pt]
&=AB^2\left(\color{#C00}{4\sin^2\left(10^{\large\circ}\right)}+\color{#090}{16\sin^2\left(20^{\large\circ}\right)\sin^2\left(40^{\large\circ}\right)}\right.\\
&\phantom{=AB^2\left(\right.}\left.{}+\color{#00F}{16\sin^2\left(10^{\large\circ}\right)\sin\left(20^{\large\circ}\right)\sin\left(40^{\large\circ}\right)}\right)\tag{3c}\\[6pt]
&=AB^2\left(\color{#C00}{2-2\cos\left(20^{\large\circ}\right)}+\color{#090}{4\cos^2\left(20^{\large\circ}\right)-4\cos\left(20^{\large\circ}\right)+1}\right.\\
&\phantom{=AB^2\left(\right.}\left.\color{#00F}{{}-4\cos^2\left(20^{\large\circ}\right)+6\cos\left(20^{\large\circ}\right)-2}\right)\tag{3d}\\[12pt]
&=AB^2\tag{3e}
\end{align}
$$
Explanation:
$\text{(1a)}$: Law of Sines
$\text{(1b)}$: $\sin\left(150^{\large\circ}\right)=\frac12$
$\text{(2a)}$: Law of Sines
$\text{(2b)}$: Law of Sines
$\text{(2c)}$: $\sin\left(30^{\large\circ}\right)=\sin\left(150^{\large\circ}\right)=\frac12$
$\text{(3a)}$: Law of Cosines
$\text{(3b)}$: apply $\text{(1b)}$ and $\text{(2c)}$
$\text{(3c)}$: $\cos\left(100^{\large\circ}\right)=-\sin\left(10^{\large\circ}\right)$
$\text{(3d)}$: use $\sin(a)\sin(b)=\frac{\cos(a-b)-\cos(a+b)}2$ to get
$\phantom{\text{(3d):}}$ $\sin^2\left(10^{\large\circ}\right)=\frac{1-\cos\left(20^{\large\circ}\right)}2$ and
$\phantom{\text{(3d):}}$ $\sin\left(20^{\large\circ}\right)\sin\left(40^{\large\circ}\right)=\frac{\cos\left(20^{\large\circ}\right)-\frac12}2$
$\text{(3e)}$: simplify

Comment: Very nice this i was expecting to be the method i wanted thanks

Answer (score 1):

[image]

Comment: In figure AF, CG and BH are altitudes of triangle.It can be shown by angle chasing that:

$\overset{\large\frown}{ED}=20^o$

$\overset{\large\frown}{DH}=40^o$

$\Rightarrow \angle DBH=20^o$

These points must be shown:

- X is on altitude AF.
- $\widehat{GCB}=10^o$

$\angle GBH=50^o$

$\Rightarrow\overset{\large\frown}{GH}=100^o$

$\triangle AFB\sim\triangle CBG$

These two triangles are symmetric about BH, that is BH bisect angle ABC; it also bisect segment AC which results in $AH=HC$ and $BA=BC$ and triangle ABC is isosceles.

Comment: I dont get what motivated you to put altitudes , and also how you intiallly proceed when giving a glance to the problem . May you please explain ?

Comment: By drawing altitudes I wanted to show: 1- X must be on altitude AF so $\triangle ABF\sim \triangle CBG$. 2- Altitude BH is to show it bisects AC and angle ABC. and get this result that AB=BC. I explained all these in my comment.

Comment: It appears that $\angle GBH$ is the complement of $\angle BAH$ which is $50^{\large\circ}$. That makes $\angle GBH=40^{\large\circ}$ and $\overset{\large\frown}{GH}=80^{\large\circ}$, not $100^{\large\circ}$.

Comment: $\triangle AFB\sim\triangle CGB$ since the right angle is at $G$. In any case, $\angle BAC=50^{\large\circ}$ and $$\begin{align}\angle BCA&=\angle BCG+\angle GCA\\&=10^{\large\circ}+40^{\large\circ}\\&=50^{\large\circ}\end{align}$$ since $\overset{\large\frown}{GH}=80^{\large\circ}$ (as shown in my last comment).